# Python regex replace alphanumeric with indent

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re, string-substitution

I'm looking to leverage regex syntax to create an indent (new line) where certain criteria is met. In this case when there is an alphanumeric value following `),` pattern.

Something like this - but it is not quite working.

```
text_old =

some text some text 
),
some text some text 
), some text some text
```

which becomes -

```
text_format = 
some text some text 
),
some text some text 
), 
some text some text
```

```
text_format = text_old.lower().replace('), ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$','), \n')
```

Do I have the proper syntax here?

EDIT

I understand that `replace` is not best approach for regex. So I have something like this, which isn't quite working -

```
re.sub(r'\),\s^\w+$','\), \n',text_old)
```

EDIT 2

I am very close, now it just cuts off the first letter it finds.

```
re.sub('\),\s\w','), \n',text_old)
```

Like this

```
text_format = 
some text some text 
),
some text some text 
), 
ome text some text
```

Where I would like it to find the pattern, not replace the first character

Comment: Not quite: `str.replace` does not support regex based search and replace. It is done with `re.sub`.

Comment: I see, is there a ```replace``` approach to this question?

Comment: You want to carry forward the part after the comma, so you will use parentheses to group it, and include  \1 in your substitution string.  Check the re.sub docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub)

Comment: something like this? ```re.sub(r'\), ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$','), \n',text_old)``` doesn't quite work

Comment: or something like ```re.sub(r'\),\s^\w+$','\), \n',text_old)``` I would think would work